# Difference between 'exec' and 'select'; prime factorization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, kdb

First, I can't understand the difference between `exec` and `select` in `kdb`. The [reference for exec](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#exec) doesn't really help much!

Second, I'm trying to write a program to solve [Euler problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5). I solved it by using `mod` and `each`, but its slow and requires a ton of space. I believe I can do it by adding up the values of 20's prime factorization. Is that correct? If so, can anyone assist me in doing so? I've written the following to get the prime factorization. It can't take in a list yet.

```
f1:{(x mod y) = 0}
f2:{if[f1[a;y]&(not max f1[y;x],0);x:x,y];x}
f3:{x+:1;y:f2[y;x];if[x<a;y:.z.s[x;y]];y}
f3[1;()
```

Comment: The whole point of Euler problems is to require out-of-the-box solution. The naive solution will not work for Euler problems. Hint: Problem 5 can be solved in under a minute by a human and a 4-function calculator, or under a second by a computer.

Comment: yep mine took 240 ms on average machine just google SOE (sieves of Eratosthenes) and LCM (least common multiply) and it should hit you also you do not need to test all numbers 1,2,3...20

Comment: -1 Please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 5):

On your first question, `exec` is essentially a more general form of `select`. A `select` query will return what you query for in a table format whereas an `exec` is more flexible and can return any type of data you want from a table.
For example, if we have a table

```
t:([]a:10?`aa`bb`cc;b:10?10)
```

Then we can use exec to get a list of column data from the table

```
q)exec a from t
`cc`aa`aa`aa`bb`aa`bb`cc`cc`cc
```

which comes in very handy at times. Also

```
q)exec a,b from t
a| cc aa aa aa bb aa bb cc cc cc
b| 6  4  1  3  3  7  8  2  1  4
q)exec a!b from t
cc| 6
aa| 4
aa| 1
aa| 3
bb| 3
aa| 7
bb| 8
cc| 2
cc| 1
cc| 4
```

which extracts dictionaries. The first takes the column names as the keys and columns as values and the second takes column a a the key and column b as the value.  A nice little example of these in use can be seen in creating a pivot table http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/.

Finally, you can get the full table using

```
exec by 0b from t
```

which is equivalent to

```
select from t
```

The `by 0b` is implicit in the select statement. In fact, you can see this by looking at the parse trees of both.

```
q)parse"exec from t"
?
`t
()
()
()
q)parse"select from t"
?
`t
()
0b
()
```

Comment: Didn't know about "exec by 0b from t". Nice One.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution for this problem will be :-

```
LCM(1,2,3,......20)=1*5*7*8*9*11*13*17*19=116396280;
```

So,develop your code for an LCM program which will give LCM of n numbers...

Comment: 20 is divisible 2,4,5,10 so you can ignore them in LCM which will speed up computation

Comment: I didn't include 20,but rather generalised in the notation,the correct one is on the RHS---right hand side!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your Second Issue, you can also use  Euclid's algorithm for fast solution.

Euclid's Algo. is used to find GCD of 2 numbers and it is very fast. It uses the property that :

GCD (a;b)= GCD (b; a mod b). This goes on till (a mod b) return 0 and once that happens,  'b' is the gcd.

Reference (Section GCD): http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=math_for_topcoders

LCM can be find using GCD.

```
  LCM of a&b = (a*b) / GCD of a & b
```

Also, one more formula that would be required is:

```
  LCM of a & b & c = LCM of (LCM of a & b) & c
```

Using the above algo and logic,here is what I tried:

```
    q) gcd:{[a;b] first {(x[1];x[0] mod x[1])}/[{0<>x[1]};(a;b)]}

    q )lcm:{[l]{floor (x*y) % gcd[x;y]}/[l]}

    q) lcm[1_til 10]
```

output: 2520

```
    q) lcm[1_til 20]
```

output: 232792560

```
    q) \ts lcm[1_til 20]
```

output: 0 864

**It takes  less than 1ms (approx .15ms) for calculation.**